# jquery hide/show effect simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create slide navigation.

My code:

```
$('.feeds_text p:visible').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300, function() {
   $('#quote_' + currentKey).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 300) 
});
```

But this functions executes in turn and creates time when we have white area between two div's in rotation. How can I use this two functions simultaneously? I need use only hide/show functions.

Comment: same element, two direction effect??? unbelievable. Would you show a demo what you wanted to do?

Comment: if you are shwoing one and hiding another use different id.

Comment: I deleted my post, I probably misunderstood the question. Look at this and tell me if it's what you wanted or not. If so I'll add it as a response. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/dn5w6/

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use the callback function,
and use `.stop()` if `'#quote_' + currentKey` has also the class `.feeds_text`

```
$('.feeds_text p:visible').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
$('#quote_' + currentKey).stop().show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 300);
```

Comment: I have small time when div has big height when first block disappears, second - apperas.

Comment: @BohdanVorona please setup a jsBin.com demo with an example. It's hard to understand what you need.